Update nextui button defaults
Is there a way to update NextUI component base styles?
i.e. I want all nextUI buttons to have a font weight of 600 instead of 400.
How do I do that?
Here's the component:
https://nextui.org/docs/components/button
I can easily go and do:
<Button color='primary' className='font-medium'>
But that seems wrong, as if a developer (or I myself) forgot to add that to the button, that would causes inconsistencies in the UI.

font-weight: 400 has been set for the font-normal class. So, you can override the font-normal class as font-weight: 600

That would change font normal behaviour everywhere which is not what I need.

Of course, you need to change for only buttons: button > .font-normal

See: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides

I think you can do it by using themeProvider to create a custom theme to modify the default style.
You should find more details here
Here an exemple of a custom theme:
// theme.js
import { createTheme } from '@nextui-org/react';

const customTheme = createTheme({
  type: 'light',
  theme: {
    components: {
      Button: {
        styles: {
          base: {
            fontWeight: 600,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default customTheme;

// App.js or index.js
import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/react';
import customTheme from './theme';

function App() {
  return (
    <NextUIProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <YourAppComponents />
    </NextUIProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

I hope this should answer you question or at least help you.

You have linked MUI documentation. I do not see the ability to change component level things in NextUI documentation. If you have a link, that would be great.
